# Laravel Schema: Null default, timestamp on update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've just started working with Laravel so am getting used to how things are done.

I've been trying to do something that I cannot seem to find an example of online. I'm using the Schema builder to create a new table.

What I want is a datetime field with the default value to be NULL, but to have "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

I've tried a number of things, but here was my latest attempt:

```
$table->dateTime('opened_on')->default(Capsule::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

With this code I get an "Invalid default value for 'opened_on'" error.

Any feedback or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The "Capsule" part is how Laravel is used in the application I'm working with.

Comment: The "Capsule" part is probably what's breaking this. I upvoted an answer that suggests using `DB::raw()` instead, which worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use this syntax for migrations:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Comment: not working for me giving erroe `Call to a member function default() on null`

Answer (score 5):

### Use [->timestamps()](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/why-table-timestamps-puts-on-update-current-timestamp-on-the-created-at-column) in laravel

```
$table->timestamp('opened_on')->useCurrent();
```

[Set Default null database table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY `opened_on` DATE DEFUALT NULL;
```

**You Have to create your database table through [migration in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations)**

Comment: How can I set the default value to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel and use built-in Laravel functionality. Just add `->timestamps()` which will create `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. When you'll update data using Eloquent, Laravel will set the current date and time to the `updated_at` column. Also, `updated_at` will be automatically converted to the Carbon instance.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions (look at the Timestamps section)

Comment: Not sure if this would work for what I am trying to do. I want the datetime of when something was opened the first time. The database record is created ahead of time, so the "created_at" record wouldn't be what I need, and while other record values can be updated in the future the datetime should not change, so "updated_at" doesn't seem to be what I need either, as updates can continue to happen to other fields in the same row, but I don't want the datetime to change.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was easier to just create a datetime field set to NULL by default, and then update the timestamp in PHP rather than let MySQL do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

You can use mutators for this.